# How can I plot this 2nd order ode?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I plot the solution curves for this ode:

$y''-4y'+5y=0$

$y(-1)=2$

$y'(-1)=0$

I solved the ode but cannot solve for C1 and C2. Thanks.

Comment: What is your general solution?

Comment: @blue3lf: Why are you having issues? You have $$y_c(x) = e^{2x}( c_1 \cos x + c_2 \sin x)$$ Now, use the two initial conditions to solve for the two constants.

Comment: I already tried to solve for C1 and C2. I end up getting $-C2sin(t)+C2sin(t)=0$ which just becomes $0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$y = C_1 e^{2t}\cos t + C_2 e^{2t} \sin t\\
y' = (2C_1 + C_2)\cos t + (2C_2-C_1)\sin t$

Now for your initial conditions.

$y(-1) =  C_1 e^{-2}\cos (-1) + C_2 e^{-2} \sin (-1)=2\\
y'(-1) = (2C_1 + C_2)\cos (-1) + (2C_2-C_1)\sin (-1) = 0$

That is going to get messy...

Here is the trick:

$y = C_1 e^{2(t+1)}\cos (t+1) + C_2 e^{2(t+1)} \sin (t+1)$

Still satisfies your diff eq.

$y(-1) =  C_1 =2\\
y'(-1) = 2C_1 + C_2= 0$

Comment: How can you just add 1 to t?

Comment: Try it out!  See if it when you differentiate and plug into your equation....  Autonomous differential equations don't depend on $t.$  Any solution that eventually goes through the point $(y(-1), y'(-1))$ traces out the same path.  And this gives us the flexibility to wind around t as is convenient.  Or you can expand out the trig functions using your identities, and you will see how the +1 factor accrues to your constants.

Comment: Wow thanks so much!

Comment: But doesn't that give C2 = -4? Which doesn't satisfy the DE.

Comment: @blue3lf , you won't get $C_2=-4$, you'll get that with offset of one $C_2=-4$. Try to factor out $e^2$ and use trig: $\cos (t+1)=\cos 1\cos t-\sin 1\sin t$(and similarly to sine), this will get you to the right answer

Answer (score 0):

A sketch is like this

[image]

with MATLAB code

```
n=3;

x=0:0.01:pi;

for i=1:n

for j=1:n

    y=exp(2.*x).*(i.*sin(x)/10+j.*cos(x)/10);

    plot(x,y,'b')

    hold on

end

end
```